# How to compile c++ without needing a

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

For school we were given a creative response for an assignment so I decided to use my amateur c++ knowledge to make a Win32 console application which was a "choose your own adventure" game. I finished it (in Visual Studio 2015) and submitted it since it worked fine on my computer I figured nothing could go wrong since my computer and the school's use Windows. But when it is run on the school's computer's It turns out it can't run because it is missing a .dll.
Turns out this is because the school's computer don't run Visual Studio and mine does.

So what I am asking is what can I do to make it so my code can run on any windows computer regardless if they have Visual Studio installed? My bad if this is a noob or impossible question.

Comment: I was just about to share an answer for you: http://imgur.com/mrZkWWw  then the question got closed. See pic.

Comment: I don't see why this question was dismissed as a "duplicate", and it seems a bit harsh. Especially given that it looks to be OP's first question here. The connection between "missing a .dll" and "fully statically linked" may not be as obvious to everyone as it is to the gold mods.